# Solr dynamicField not searched in query without field name

Tags: solr, schema

I'm experimenting with the Example database in Solr 4.10 and not understanding how `dynamicFields` work.  The schema defines

```
dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"
```

If I add a new item with a new field name (say `"example_s":"goober"` in JSON format), a query like

```
?q=goober
```

returns no matches, while

```
?q=example_s:goober
```

will find the match. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the SearchHandler from solrconfig.xml file that you are using to execute the above mentioned query.

In SearchHandler we generally have Default Query Field i.e. qf parameter.

Check that your dynamic field **example_s** is present in that query field list of solrconfig file else you can pass it while sending query to search handler.

Hope this will help you in resolving your problem.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, however after updating the list of fields in the qf parameter, restarting Solr, and reindexing the documents, it still won't work.  Solr seems to take the opposite approach to Elasticsearch; I was up and running with Elasticsearch in a matter of minutes, because the default configuration indexes everything.  The default config for Solr basically indexes nothing until you tell it what to index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default schema, here's what's happening:

1. You are probably using default end-point (/select), so you get the definition of search type and parameters from that. Which means, it is default (lucene) search and [the field searched is text](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml#L843).
2. The text field is an aggregate and is populated by [copyField instruction from other fields](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L271).
3. Your [dynamic field definition for *_s](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L203) allows you to index the text with any name ending in _s, such as example_s. It's indexed (so you could search against it directly) and stored (so you can see it when you ask for all fields). It will not however search it as a general text. Notice that (differently from ElasticSearch), Solr strings have to be matched fully and completely. If you have some multi-word text in it, there is barely any point searching it. "goober" is one word so it's not a very good example to understand the difference here.
4. The easiest solution for you is add another copyField instruction: 
   `<copyField source="*_s" dest="text"/>`, then all your *_s dynamic fields would also be searchable. But notice that the search analyzers will **not** be the ones for *_s definition, but the ones [for the **text** field's definition](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L169), which is not string, but text_general, defined elsewhere in the file.

As to Solr vs. ElasticSearch, they both err on the different sides of magic. Solr makes you configure the system and makes it very easy to see the exact current configuration. ElasticSearch hides all of the configuration, but you have to rediscover it the second you want to change away from the default behaviour. In the end, the result is probably similar and meets somewhere in the middle.